# Java JPanel checkbox actionlistener will not un-editable JtextFields

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, hashmap

I have a panel with several JTextFields with a corresponding checkbox next to each of those - these are linked in pairs via a map.
I have written the code that when each checkbox is selected or deselected, the corresponding JTextFields are made uneditable or editable, respectively (this is done without the map). This part works well.

However I wish to have a single checkbox that can control all of the JTextFields in this way. I thought the best way to do this would be by iterating through the map key/value pairs so that if I want to add more boxes/fields later then I could do so easily and just add those to the map. Currently in my code, when I select this main checkbox (checkBoxAllNormal) all the JTextFields become uneditable (as intended), however when I deselect the main checkbox, the JTextFields remain uneditable.

```
    map.put(checkBox_1, textField);
    map.put(checkBox_2, textField_1);
    map.put(checkBox_3, textField_2);
    map.put(checkBox_4, textField_3);

    JCheckBox checkBoxAllNormal = new JCheckBox("");
    checkBoxAllNormal.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (checkBoxAllNormal.isSelected()){
                Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
                while(it.hasNext()){
                    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                    ((JTextField) pair.getValue()).setEditable(false);
                    it.remove();
                }
            }
            else{
                Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
                while(it.hasNext()){
                    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                    ((JTextField) pair.getValue()).setEditable(true);
                    it.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

From what I can tell the issue is with the second

```
  while(it.hasNext()){
```

But I don't know why or how to fix this, but I have the feeling my use of maps is probably the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't find what the issue was, I've found a way to iterate through the map which works correctly. I think the issue lay with the process I was using to iterate.

```
    JCheckBox checkBoxAllNormal = new JCheckBox("");
    checkBoxAllNormal.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (checkBoxAllNormal.isSelected()){
                for(Entry<JCheckBox,JTextField> entry: map.entrySet()){
                    entry.getValue().setEditable(false);
                }
            }
            else{
                for(Entry<JCheckBox,JTextField> entry: map.entrySet()){
                    entry.getValue().setEditable(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I'll leave this question up in case it helps someone in the future.